# How can I add the value into dictionary with the key from looping the list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have an excel file with 39 columns and 10000 rows.

I would like to store the key and value in list.

I can only come up with

```
    result = []
    temp = {}
    for x in range (1, 10000):
        for y in range (1, 39):
             # title and sheet also come from the excel 
             temp[ title[y] ] : SHEET.cell_value(x, y)
             result.append(temp)
```

The code I wrote didn't running as I expected so how can I rewrite it?

I would like to expect the result would be:

```
result = [
    {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, ...},
    {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, ...},
    {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, ...},
    ....
]
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want using something like pandas ? ([pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) will take care of all the indexing business...)

Comment: If you decide @tgrandje 's answer is not for you, please provide EXACT input and EXACT desired output, in a more minimal manner, so that we can help you

Comment: @tgrandje Gulzar The reason why I don't use pandas was I need to transform the value before export CSV, anyway I tried pandas and it works as well, thanks for you two advices

Comment: @WKenny : pandas will allow you to transform datas just as well (for example, you can use df.loc[0, 'a"] = 5 which is the same as result[0]['a'] = 5 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, using Pandas is probably the way to go. However, if you wish to implement a solution using plain Python, and assuming you have `SHEET` and `title` objects defined, this is probably what you want:

```
result = []
for x in range (1, 10000):
    temp = {}
    for y in range (1, 39):
         # title and sheet also come from the excel 
         temp[ title[y] ] = SHEET.cell_value(x, y)
    result.append(temp)
```

Comment: That's the ans I am looking for anyway~ If anyone face the same problem, mkam 's ans would be a solve and Pandas is only the other solve

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas, it may be easier...

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(my_url)
print(df.to_dict('r'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I will use Pandas. To install first run from Cmd or terminal:

```
pip install -U pandas
```

Then import excel sheet with [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("EXCEL SHEET PATH")
```

And then to dictionary [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
print(df.to_dict())
```